# Tastypie APIKey authentication

Tags: django, tastypie, api-key

How does the Tastypie APIKey authentication work?  I know there is a signal as mentioned in the documentation:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
from django.db import models  
from tastypie.models import create_api_key 

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)
```

However, when is this called? If I want to give a user their APIkey I know I can find it in the APIKey db that this create_api_key function adds the key into, but where and when do I call this models.signals.post_save function?

Is this just another django model?  I think it is?

Is this called everytime a user account is saved?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can put this in `models.py` file of the relevant app (such as `main/`). What `post_save.connect(create_api_key, sender=User)` does is that everytime an `User` instance is saved, `create_api_key()` will be called.

Now let's look into what `create_api_key()` does by diving a bit into the source of [**tastypie**](https://bitbucket.org/dc/django-tastypie/src/ee13e251ace5/tastypie/models.py):

```
class ApiKey(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='api_key')
    key = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s for %s" % (self.key, self.user)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.key:
            self.key = self.generate_key()

        return super(ApiKey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def generate_key(self):
        # Get a random UUID.
        new_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
        # Hmac that beast.
        return hmac.new(str(new_uuid), digestmod=sha1).hexdigest()


def create_api_key(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal for hooking up automatic ``ApiKey`` creation.
    """
    if kwargs.get('created') is True:
        ApiKey.objects.create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

As you can see, `create_api_key()` will create a new `ApiKey` record, which will be related to the calling `User`. This record will also have a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) key when it was saved to the `ApiKey` table. The key is generated by `generate_key()` function.

Comment: awesome perfect... thanks. So if I change a user's account information will api key change then as well (say the password is changed)?

Comment: Nope, the API key will only be created when a new user record is `created`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save . Basically, when new `User` record is created, a `created=True` parameter will be sent to `create_api_key()`, updating `User` will not set `created=True` thus not triggering the ApiKey creation.

Comment: Im not clear on this, so can you pass create_api_key for an existing user?  If not how do you create one for an existing user?

Comment: @Dave I am not sure what you mean by the first question, but create_api_key is a signal that is not called by updating existing user, if this answers your question.. Second one, the quick (and possibly dirty) way is write a simple script for all users who doesn't have a key, so that it `generate_key` for them and stores it to `ApiKey` table at their row.